# Why is there no article in this sentence?

Tags: articles, nouns, modifiers

Here's the sentence:

> Enter University of Cambridge zoologist Ricardo Rocha.

It is a complete sentence from an IELTS text. My question is: why is there no article before 'university,' as 'University of Cambridge' here plays the role of a modifier, and the word 'zoologist,' which is modified, requires an article? Moreover, why shouldn't 'University of Cambridge' be preceded by the definite article anyway?

Comment: It's an informal way of saying _the zoologist Ricardo Rocha, from the University of Cambridge_. _Zoologist_ acts like an adjective describing Mr Rocha, and _University of Cambridge_ like an adjective modifying _zoologist_.

Comment: Or it could be a stage direction from a play 

Comment: @PeterJennings - stage left?

Comment: I agree with Kate, except that "enter [some character] is **a stage direction as given in a play**.

Comment: I thought at first that it was the use of _Enter_ that puzzled the OP - but as he didn't mention it, I didn't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"University of Cambridge" acts as a modifying noun phrase to modify "zoologist" and "University of Cambridge zoologist" is an appositional phrase to the proper noun "Richard Rocha". These nouns don't need articles as they are part of modifying phrases.

"Richard Rocha" doesn't have an article as it is a proper noun.

The whole sentence seems to be imperative, perhaps it is a stage direction, or is emulating a stage direction for rhetorical purposes.